# Vue - How to add directive to a created Element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Lets say I create an Element with

```
let centerIconDiv = document.createElement('div');
centerIconDiv.className += 'centerIcon box-shadow m-2 rounded-2';
```

And add this to google maps

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(centerIconDiv);
```

How do I add Vue directive to the "centerIconDiv"? I want to have something like v-if or v-show and add :class etc.

I can't really find the solution, because I don't need to render a template. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this is the best answer to your question, but you can manually mount a globally registered Vue component after you instantiate the component like so:

```js
// This was taken from the docs
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">item #{{ $vnode.key }}: You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})

// This appends the new component with directives:
$('#components-demo').append(`
  <button-counter v-for="i in [1,2,3,4,5]" v-if="i % 2 === 0" :key="i"></button-counter>
`)

// This registers the component, activating the directives
new Vue({ el: '#components-demo' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="components-demo"></div>
```

Another thing you could do is make the parent of both your Google Maps element and the vue component into a component, itself, and include the logic for instantiating the new vue components into that parent component, which would probably be a better pattern to maintain.

Comment: thank you! It didn't work in the first time, because the component did not want to render. So I had to find out how to rerender the component. I'm not sure if my way is okay, but it works